# how does django handle password in form

Tags: django

I'm following django docs and got confused with django form model.
I'm trying to build a user signup page with custom user class

```
CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default="")
```

and I also defined a form

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.CharField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

a view

```
class SignUpView(View):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(True)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

an Admin

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):    
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (('Misc', {'fields': ('description', 'location')}),)
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (('Misc', {'fields': ('description', 'location')}),)


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

question is how this form will handle password field, since there's only one password field in CustomUser Model, and how this form map to CustomModel
And what if I want to seperate backend and front end and use pure html/js form instead, do I still need to define a form, if yes, how should I map it to model and html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* include any of the passwords in the `fields`. You should *not* store a password in a `CharField` directly in your model. Django has a [**`set_password(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) defined to set the password. This will hash the password.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.CharField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'location')

    def clean_password2(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if not pwd1 or not pwd2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password is empty')
        if pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match')
        return pwd2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        customuser = super().save(commit=False)
        customuser.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            customuser.save()
        return customuser
```

Here the `clean_password2` will thus validate that both passwords are filled in, and match. In the `save(..)` method we will use `set_password` on our `customeruser` object to save the hashed password.

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem.But I still have a question to add, about seperating frontend and backend.If I'm not gonna use django-populated form for html. do I still need to define Form class mapping to model, or just save to model with simple request args

Comment: @X.Z. as far as I know, `django-populated` does not use forms? It will just take the model into account. Note that the password that it will store in the database, is not the password to authenticate with, since that is a hashed variant.